# Why do I need an .ipa file?

Tags: ios

I'm using XCode 6.1.1, ios8 and MacOSX Yosemite.

When I click "Run on device", all I seem to get is an .app file. It runs fine on the device.
Why and when would I need an .ipa file?
You can direct me to relevant docs, I really cant seem to find any official, general info on this.

Answer (score 1):

An .ipa is an archive containing your .app. It's useful when you want to share your application to others.

You can install an .ipa from Itunes for example, or by direct download from a server.

Comment: so the reason I cant just use .app files directly is because the installation process used by xcode is hidden behind proprietary code and only itunes is allowed to only use .ipa files to install apps without xcode?

Comment: To be honest I never tried to install a .app with iTunes. I guess it should not work.
But yeah, .ipa is the way you should go to share your app

Answer (score 0):

Just to append. .app is not a file, but a Folder, which would be hard to distribute to the users, but all is said in previous comment.

More in wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension%29